# How to set image attributes to the division of two other attributes?

Tags: jquery, image, loops

I am trying to loop a JQuery function through a series of images with the class "img-cover", so that each image has is assigned a bgHeight, bgWidth, and bgRatio variable value that corresponds to that image's width, height, and aspect ratio, respectively. However I am having difficulty assigning these variables to each image in the loop. Any input is appreciated!

Original JQuery (for a static 1500x2250 image):

```
var bgHeight = 1500;                            
var bgWidth = 2250;                              
var bgRatio = bgHeight / bgWidth;
```

My attempt to loop through multiple images:

```
$('.img-cover').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('bgHeight',$(this).height());
    $(this).attr('bgWidth',$(this).width());
    $(this).attr('bgRatio',$(this).bgHeight() / $(this).bgWidth());
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling two undefined functions here:

```
$(this).bgHeight() / $(this).bgWidth() //no such functions in jQuery, unless you've added them
```

jQuery's [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) works this way: if you pass it two parameters, it is a «setter». If you only need to get an attribute's value, use `attr()` with only one parameter:

```
$(this).attr('bgWidth') //gets the value of an attribute called 'bgWidth'
```

Apart from this, there are some code style issues. 1) You can save `$(this)` to a variable inside your function. 2) You don't have to take bgWidth and bgHeight from attributes — they are equal to width() and height() values inside one iteration. Save them into variables w, h and work with them:

```
$('.img-cover').each(function() {
    var $img = $(this),
        w = $img.width(),
        h = $img.height();
    $img.attr('bgHeight', h);
    $img.attr('bgWidth', w);
    $img.attr('bgRatio', h / w);
});
```